# Update quote statement

Tags: c#, sql

I am writing an update statement. I think my SQL statement is opening me up for SQL injections.  Is there a better to do this?

```
public void UpdateQuote(string quote, string quote_id)
{
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection) {
    string query = "Update quotes set quotes = '"+quote+"', updated_at = NOW() where id_quotes = '"+quote_id+"'";
    dbConnection.Open();
    dbConnection.Execute(query, quote);
}
```

Comment: yes it does, google "c# sql prepared statements"

Comment: You are missing a closing `}`

Comment: Where is the `Execute(string, string)` coming from ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can parametize a command and execute it.

```
using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
{
    using (DbCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE quotes "
                        + "SET quotes = @Quote, "
                        + "updated_at = NOW() "
                        + "WHERE id_quotes = @QuoteID";

        IDbDataParameter quoteParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
        quoteParam.ParameterName = "@Quote";
        quoteParam.Value = quote;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(quoteParam);
        IDbDataParameter quoteIdParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
        quoteIdParam.ParameterName = "@QuoteID";
        quoteIdParam.Value = quote_id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(quoteIdParam);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This isn't the most elegant solution, but should serve your needs.

I wasn't sure about your Connection variable, but it should be open at time of execution.

Comment: Without knowing the underlaying database system the provided parameter identifier `@` may be wrong

Answer (score -1):

The `{ }` don't match up. Let's start with valid syntax:

```
public void UpdateQuote(string quote, string quote_id)
{
    using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection) 
    {
        string query = "Update quotes set quotes = '" + quote + "', updated_at = NOW() where id_quotes = '" + quote_id + "'";
        dbConnection.Open();
        dbConnection.Execute(query, quote);
    }
}
```

Sharing a `Connection` like this is not a good practice. If it is used by other threads, things go bad.

`dbConnection` is just a reference. I am not sure if `Connection` is Disposed.

Yes, you are exposed to SQL injection.